GCP Load Balancer Returning 503: No Healthy Upstream in GKE, NGINX with Flask Backend
I'm having trouble with a GCP global load balancer setup using GKE, NGINX (serving a React frontend), and a Flask backend. The load balancer consistently returns 503 No Healthy Upstream, even though the services appear to be working correctly inside the cluster.
Setup:

Frontend: React served via NGINX
Backend: Flask (Python 3.11) running on GKE
Load Balancer: GCP Global HTTP(S) Load Balancer with SSL

Problem:
Despite everything appearing functional within the cluster, the load balancer keeps marking my backend instances as unhealthy, resulting in a 503 error. Curling the backend service from inside the cluster works fine, but the load balancer isn't passing traffic correctly.
Configuration Details:
NGINX Configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /health {
        proxy_pass http://backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local:80/health;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

Dockerfile for NGINX/Frontend:
# Stage 1: Build the React app
FROM node:16-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve with NGINX
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Backend (Flask) Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:80", "run:app"]

Service YAML (Backend):
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: backend
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 1.2.3.4

What I've already tried:

Health Checks:

Health checks are configured to hit /health on port 80, and they work inside the cluster (200 OK).
External health checks from the load balancer fail, marking all instances as unhealthy.


Firewall Rules:

Ingress rules are in place to allow traffic on ports 80 and 443 from all IPs.


SSL Configuration:

The SSL certificate is provisioned and active for the domain.
Curling the HTTPS endpoint directly results in a 503 error with no healthy upstream.


Testing Internally:

Curling the backend service from inside the frontend pod works fine:

kubectl exec -it frontend-pod -- curl http://backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local/health
{"status":"ok"}


DNS and SSL:

Domain is set up with GCP Cloud DNS, pointing to the correct IP (1.2.3.4).
The SSL certificate is successfully provisioned for the domain.



Current Behavior:

Internal health checks from GCP keep failing.
Curling the backend service from within the cluster works, but the load balancer sees the instances as unhealthy.
Any attempt to access the service externally through the load balancer results in a 503 error (no healthy upstream).

Questions:

Why does the load balancer consistently mark the backend as unhealthy, even though internal health checks pass?
Is there a specific GKE or load balancer setting I might be missing?
How can I resolve the 503 No Healthy Upstream issue with this configuration?

